# Minecraft regular texture not showing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I'm making customModelData glasses using the pumpkin. My custom glasses are working perfectly but the regular pumpkin texture is not showing.

The content of my models/carved_pumpkin.json

```
{
    "parent":"item/handeld",
    "textures":{
        "layer0":"block/carved_pumpkin"
    },
    "overrides":[
        {"predicate":{"custom_model_data":101}, "model":"item/custom_models/cool_glasses"}
    ]
}
```

I'm playing in 1.19

I was expecting the regular pumpkin texture to show but I get the black and purple texture. When the CustomModelData is set to 101, my glasses shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a very easy fix. The problem is your parent configuration.
The unmodified game uses the following json for the `carved_pumpkin`.

```
{
  "parent": "minecraft:block/carved_pumpkin"
}
```

I would suggest to just remove the textures part and set the parent to `minecraft:block/carved_pumpkin`.